# Intel xdk doesn't let me make Ajax calls

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cross-domain, intel-xdk

I had a PhoneGap project which I have imported into Intel XDK. Evetything is working as before except that I am unable to process Ajax calls. After reading the documentation I add the following two lines before all other scripts:

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
<script src="xhr.js"></script>
```

But that still doesn't have any impact.

I am using jQuery $get to process Ajax Calls. Something like this:

```
$.get( MyURL, function( data ) {
    alert(data);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is the XDK that isn't allowing AJAX calls? Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No I am not getting any errors. And I am pretty sure that it started happening after moving the code to XDK. Same code is working in PhoneGap perfectly in an Android Released App.

Comment: @anjum try using the $.ajax() call, it should work

Comment: Tried. No luck. Even tried getJSON without success.

Comment: alert("Out-1");
 $.getJSON('http://myserver.com/json1.php?callback=?', function (results) {
  alert("Inside Json");
  alert ( JSON.stringify(results) );
 });
 alert("Out-2");

Comment: @Anjum what is the real URL?

Comment: @krisrak. Thanks for follow up. I have actually given and rather started learning xCode / Objective C to avoid these issues :-(

Answer (score 5):

Here is a working example of AJAX call in Intel XDK, you can try it in Intel XDK and on device, replace the URL with yours and try:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX and XDK</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
    <script>
        function doAJAX() {
            $.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:'http://time.jsontest.com/',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data))
                }
            });
        }
</script>
<style>
    body {font-family:arial;background-color:white}
</style>    
</head>
<body>         
    <h3>AJAX Call</h3>
    <button onclick="doAJAX()">AJAX Call</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @krisrak: But its a bit too late :-) After not being able to successfully use Ajax with XDK I decided to move my PhoneGap Project to xCode where it was working perfectly, just like Android.
Thanks anyone, once again.

Comment: Wasn't too late for me. Really appreciate the example.